# How to fetch a variable value from .ts file in .scss file

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to change the opacity of a image. My css code in scss is shown below:

`home.scss` code

```
img {
    filter: grayscale(70%);
}
```

How can I change the `grayscale` variable dynamically ?

I have taken input field in html, I want this to get the value I type there, that's all:

my `page.html` code:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input name="imgg" [(ngModel)]="imgg" placeholder="enter"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button (click)="cli()" >Submit</button>
</ion-list>
<img src="../assets/icon/Stickers-20.png" width="300" height="300">
```

`page.ts` code:

```
cli() {
  this.imgg;
  console.log(this.imgg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

consider using `ngStyle` directive to bind the value dynamically to the filter value just like this:

in your component

```
grayScaleValue = 70 // assign it any value in your component
```

in your template

```
<img src="../assets/icon/sticker-20.png" [ngStyle]="{'filter': 'grayscale(' + grayScaleValue + ')%'}"
```

Comment: this is my html `<img src="../assets/icon/Stickers-20.png" width="300" height="300" [ngStyle]="{'filter':grayScaleValue+'%'}">` , added variable in .ts aswell, not working

Comment: check the Hamed's response: it's {'filter':'grayscale('+grayScaleValue+'%)'}